# UITextView shouldChangeTextInRange delegate not called

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I am using this code to set the parameters of an uitextview i have on my view.

```
_textview=[[UITextView alloc]init];
[_textview setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
_textview.text=@"Write your message";
_textview.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
_textview.layer.cornerRadius=6;
_textview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
_textview.delegate=self;
```

I have in the .h this code

```
IBOutlet UITextView *_textview;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *_textview;
```

I have connected the outlet to the uitextview by using the interface.

What happens is the following:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)inTextView
```

the above delegate is called but not the following one:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Why is this happening? Am i doing something wrong?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Did you say you connected the textfield outlet using IB?

Comment: Yes NJones the textview is connected using the Interface Builder...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to removing the `_textview = [[UITextView alloc]init];` so as to not overwrite your nib loaded textview.

The `<UITextViewDelegate>` method is:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{}
```

The correct method signature is:

```
textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:
```

not:

```
textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:
```

Comment: THanks for answering i removed the init code but still not firing!! only the textviewdidchange is firing...

Comment: Oh my god i am so stupid! Thank you so much NJones! This is so frustrating the compiler did not gave me a warning or error! Thanks again!

Comment: Don't feel too bad the first time I looked at your question all I saw was the double alloc.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are typing the method name wrong.

There is no

`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

but only

`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`

careful with the different between `replacementString` and `replacementText`.

Also, as the others said, if you've created the UITextView in IB, you should NOT init it again in your code (but this is not the reason why your delegate never invoked).

Comment: Thanks you are right but i accepted NJones answer because it posted before yours.